# How to convert a CABasicAnimation to UIView animatewithDuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, cabasicanimation, animatewithduration

I want to convert a CABasicAnimation to UIView animatewithDuration , If there is any possible to do that?

This is my tried code so far

```
CABasicAnimation *myAni = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];
myAni.duration = 2.0f;
myAni.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
myAni.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0];

[self.myView addAnimation:scaleAnimation forKey:@"myKey"];
```

to be in `[UIView animateWithDuration...`. (Instead of `CABasicAnimation`, I want it in `animationWithDuration` in the `animations` block.)

Is this possible? If so, how?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     //I need it here
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:1.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         //self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0,1.0);
                     self.testview.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(2.0,1.0,1.0);

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     }];
```

Comment: How can I use CATransform instead?

Comment: What do you mean by `CATransform instead`?

Comment: Instead of using `CGAffinTransformMakeScale`, I want to use `CATransform3DMakeScale`

Comment: Actually never mind. I got it. Also, Is it possible to have another animateWithDuration in the completion block?

Comment: See update,just set transform of Layer.You can start animation in completion block

Comment: When I do that, the view disappears! (The duration is set to 1.0)

Comment: That only happens when I set the first value of `CATransform...` to 0.0. When I set it to 1.5 it works fine. How can I get it not to disappear the the value is set to 0.0?

Comment: If your scale is zero,means that the width is zero! You cannot see zero width.It is still there

Comment: You're right, but I don't even see it animating to 0?

Comment: Set it to 0.001,not zero. If you set it to zero,animation will not happen

Comment: Thanks!! Why does it make you do that? Why can't you just animate it to 0.0?

Comment: Cannot say it clear in just words.It is a matrix problem.You may refer to tis link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964224/cgaffinetransformscale-not-working-with-zero-scale